# best practice to make string int and check if string is not int

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
<?php

function s2int($pinned_id) { 
$action="aaa";
if ( $action && is_numeric($pinned_id) && (float)$pinned_id==(int)$pinned_id) {
   /**
   * @param [string] $action is setted
   * @param [int/string as int] $pinned_id is setted
   */
echo "-chekpoint- $pinned_id\n";
    $pinned_id = (int)$pinned_id;
} 
else { echo "-passpoint- $pinned_id\n";}
return $pinned_id;
}

echo s2int("000010")."\n";
echo s2int(10.00001)."\n";
echo s2int(10)."\n";
echo s2int("10")."\n";
echo s2int("0")."\n";
echo s2int("a")."\n";
echo s2int("a10")."\n";
echo s2int("10a")."\n";
echo s2int("0x1A")."\n";
echo s2int("-100")."\n";
```

OUTPUT:

```
-chekpoint- 000010
10
-passpoint- 10.00001
10.00001
-chekpoint- 10
10
-chekpoint- 10
10
-chekpoint- 0
0
-passpoint- a
a
-passpoint- a10
a10
-passpoint- 10a
10a
-chekpoint- 0x1A
0
-chekpoint- -100
-100
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
-chekpoint- 000010
10
-passpoint- 10.00001
10.00001
-chekpoint- 10
10
-chekpoint- 10
10
-chekpoint- 0
0
-passpoint- a
a
-passpoint- a10
a10
-passpoint- 10a
10a
-passpoint- 0x1A
0x1A
-chekpoint- -100
-100
```

what is best practice to make s2int to return correct (int) variable and make action if variable can't be converted to  (int)   (as you see result unexpected if input is hexadecimal ?

http://codepad.org/lN84HKzV

Comment: The cast check with float and int is bound to fail sometime in the near future.

Comment: floats internally **aren't** integers. they are an approximate representation of the real number.

Comment: yes, that because i used `==` instead of `===`

Comment: `--` does not mean roughly equal to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [`filter_var()`](https://www.php.net/filter_var) for that:

```
if (false === ($x = filter_var($pinned_id, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT))) {
    echo "Could not convert $pinned_id to an integer";
}
// $x is an integer
```

The case of `000010` was ambiguous, as it could mean octal as well; but if you want a 10-base number, you have to strip any leading zeroes:

```
$num = preg_replace('/^0+(\d+)/', '\\1', $pinned_id);
if (false === ($x = filter_var($num, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT))) {
    echo "Could not convert $pinned_id to an integer";
}
// $x is an integer
```

If you also want to allow hexadecimal:

```
if (false === ($x = filter_var($num, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array(
    'flags' => FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_HEX,
))) {
    echo "Could not convert $pinned_id to an integer";
}
// $x is an integer
```

**Edit**

You could also go for the `preg_match()` route:

```
function s2int($pinned_id) { 
    echo "/$pinned_id/  ";
    if (!preg_match('/^-?\d+$/', $pinned_id)) {
        echo "Could not convert $pinned_id to an integer";
        return false;
    }
    return (int)$pinned_id;
}
```

*This won't run on codepad for some reason, but it should run on any other system*

Comment: @eicto what's the expected output? 8 or 10?

Comment: @eicto added two more options

Comment: ok, so for now best condition looks like:

`(false === ($x = filter_var(preg_replace('/^0+(\d)/','$1',$pinned_id), FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)))`

http://codepad.org/1Wv59VmO
any ideas how to make it look better ?

Comment: @eicto Better in what way? I doubt it can be made shorter and the regular expression is actually required for the zero padded numbers; btw, it's `'\\1'` instead of `'$1'`

Comment: \\1 is equal to '$1', i mean better, is "when you see it in code without comment you not run out with screaming"

Comment: if we have to use preg_ we can skip FILTER as i understand, which i tried to avoid.
http://codepad.org/pETBVtbp
 (codepad not works with preg_match, so i had to use replace)

Comment: @eicto I've added a plain `preg_match()` solution as well.

Comment: 11 could be base 10 (11), base 8 (9), base 2 (3). it depends on what you're using the numbers for and what youre treating them as

Answer (score 0):

```
function s2int($pinned_id) {
// use regex (regular expression)
$pattern = "/[a-zA-Z.]/";
$bool = preg_match($pattern, $pinned_id);

// check if $pinned_id is without any character in the $pattern
if ( $bool == false ) {
    /**
     * @param [string] $action is setted
     * @param [int/string as int] $pinned_id is setted
     */
    echo "-chekpoint- $pinned_id<br />";
    $pinned_id = (int)$pinned_id;
} else { 
    echo "-passpoint- $pinned_id<br />";
}
    return $pinned_id;
}
```

Comment: jfyi:

the pattern for not digits looks like /[^\d]/

Comment: with sign it would be like [^\-\+\d]

Comment: nice. then try it. this is just a generic sample anyway. and thanks.

Comment: by the way, integer can be negative

Comment: did you ever heard about signed and unsigned int ?